# Spatial joining (nearest) between features that fulfill query?

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join, proximity

I have two point feature classes, one with locations wildfires were discovered, and one where lightning strikes were detected. Both feature classes contain temporal information. For each fire, I want to search for lighting strikes within a 5 km buffer that were recorded on the day that the fire was discovered or any of the three days prior.

I believe the below process is fairly straightforward, but I am having trouble coming up with a proper iterative solution.

1. Draw a buffer of 5 km
2. Clip lightning to buffer
3. Select lightning by querying date range
4. Use *Near* to join closest lightning strike attributes to fire

How can I most effectively perform this process iteratively over each point in the fire feature class?

Comment: Try [Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) with join operation `JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY` (to handle more than one lightning strike within 5 km) and match_option `WITHIN_A_DISTANCE`. Then select by date fields in the output.

Comment: You have tags for ArcPy and ModelBuilder but have not presented any code or model.

Comment: I suspect I added those tags before deciding against discussing ArcPy or ModelBuilder specifically—my apologies. I've revised the tags.